# PHP after header location do something

Tags: php, redirect, printing, header, refresh

I need help, how can I do anything after I sent header?
When I sent data, then I would like to refresh or redirect page.
Maybe something check if printing finished...

```
header("Location: quickprinter://" . $textEncoded );
```

After this it stay on the page, but I can’t add more function like a refresh or redirect.

```
//This line not working:
header("Refresh: 1; url=/index.php");

//This line is overwriting the printing:
header("Location: /index.php");
```

Any idea would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: A redirect is a waiver of control to the redirected page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: You need to include inline code span so the code is readable & verifiable.

Comment: You cannot send headers after printing anything.